# Contact Form 7 - how to disable spinner the right way

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

The Contact Form 7 plugin includes a spinner that appears when the form is being submitted. How can I stop this spinner from showing up? I don't want to use the methods of hiding it with "hidden" or "display:none" because this still causes the spinner to load and can cause a layout shift. What is another solution to prevent the spinner from running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put this snippet ...

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
```

... in your child-themes **functions.php** and just like that, the matter is solved.

Comment: This has the problem that the response form is not shown, since if you have a custom response (ok or fail), it will not appear

Answer (score 1):

If you're still seeing the spinner after adding this CSS

```css
   .wpcf7-spinner {
      display: none !important;
      visibility: hidden !important;
    }
```

then you're CSS selector isn't specific enough and you can try adding more selectors to increase specificity.

It's not necessary to completely disable CF7 Javascript to simply hide the spinner.

Comment: This is better solution if you have a custom response form to show after the response is received (ok or fail)